# CSS - Table mode how to display correctly?

Tags: html, css

Good night stackoverflow community!

I'm trying to create a table-like model using CSS but having hard time to figure it out.
It's a table with text and some images on each row, I've tried the *display: table* property but got no success on making rows and cells. What I'm trying to do is as follows:

[image: Simple to make on paint, sweating to turn CSS]

I've tried to apply this css I created to make it at least a table but got no success. Is there anything else I have to put in my css? I really don't want to use tables.

```
#tabelona {
display: table;
}

#linha {
display: table-row;
}

#conteudo {
display: table-cell;
}
```

Here's the HTML part, I'm just using text first:

```
    <div id="tabelona">
        <div id="linha">
            <div id="conteudo">1.</div>
            <div id="conteudo">OK</div>
        </div>
    <div id="linha">
        <div id="conteudo">2.</div>
        <div id="conteudo">OK Too</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It may be beneficial for you to show us how you're structuring your HTML as well, in attempting to get your desired layout.

Comment: Serlite is right. show us the html with your css structure. We need to know what your using to achieve this other than your css. whether your using <div>, <span> or other means.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: if it *is* a table... why are you trying to avoid using a table?

Comment: @TarynEast, for this chart I want to use CSS tables instead of HTML conventional ones.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't told us why? is it just for the experience of trying it? Is it to thumb your nose at the table-using masses? or is there some actual reason why tables don't work for this implementation?

Comment: @TarynEast for the experience of using CSS tables instead of conventional ones. Sorry if I did sound rude on last comment.

Comment: Hmmmm **1.** then **2.**, looks like an ordered list (`ol`) to me.

Comment: What do you mean it works?..

Comment: @jacelysh please do not make edits that change the context of the question! You seem to have to obscured the initial problem.

Comment: @Patrick - cool no probs - it's just always good to know, in case there's some other solution that works better. :) Clearly, if you're trying it to see how it's done... then no other solution will achieve that :)

Comment: I've rolled back jacelysh's change. @jacelysh - this sort of suggested change is best done as a comment or an answer.

Comment: Hey @Patrick - what happens when you do as jacelysh suggests and change the ids to classes?

Comment: @TarynEast, everything works as I planned. If Jacelysh puts as an answer I'll gladly upvote and give best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works fine for me :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #table {
            display: table;
            margin:auto;
            border-collapse: separate;
            /* Only works if border-collapse is separate */
            border-spacing: 0 2px;
        }
        .row {
            display: table-row;
        }
        .cell {
            display: table-cell;
            border:1px solid black;
            width:100px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        /* remove some cell border to stick to your example */
        .cell:first-child {
            border-right:0 solid black;
        }
        .cell:last-child {
            border-left:0 solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="table">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">1.</div>
                <div class="cell">OK</div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">2.</div>
            <div class="cell">OK Too</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```